# Asp Net Core SignalR

Tags: c#, websocket, asp.net-core, signalr

Возможно ли взаимодействовать с asp core signalr хабом, использую на клиенте чистые веб сокеты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, это возможно. Для начала необходимо получить идентификатор соединения для установления соединения. Это можно сделать отправив запрос [Post] /yourhub/negotiate. В ответ вы получите что-то вроде этого:

```
{
    "connectionId": "g15SD5Ttcu2FwI8Zup9BoQ",
    "availableTransports": [
        {
            "transport": "WebSockets",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text",
                "Binary"
            ]
        },
        {
            "transport": "ServerSentEvents",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text"
            ]
        },
        {
            "transport": "LongPolling",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text",
                "Binary"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

После этого можно устанавливать сокетное соединение по адресу: ws://yourhost/yuorhub/?id=g15SD5Ttcu2FwI8Zup9BoQ.